# How to solve 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'secure_url' of null' in React

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, cloudinary

I am using Cloudinary to upload images, then display the image and the URL. My images are uploading but I am getting cannot display either the image or the URL because I am getting a TypeError in my if (response.body.secure_url !== ''. I've researched and read that it's because maybe I'm  accessing a property of an object that is null

App.js

```
this.state = {
      uploadedFile: null,
      uploadedFileCloudinaryUrl: ''
    };
  }

  onImageDrop(files) {
    this.setState({
      uploadedFile: files[0]
    });

    this.handleImageUpload(files[0]);
  }

  handleImageUpload(file) {
    let upload = request.post(CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_URL)
                     .field('upload_preset', CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET)
                     .field('file', file);


    upload.end((err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }

      if (response.body.secure_url !== '') {
        this.setState({
          uploadedFileCloudinaryUrl: response.body.secure_url
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div className="FileUpload">
      <Dropzone
        onDrop={this.onImageDrop.bind(this)}
        accept="image/*"
        multiple={false}>
        {({getRootProps, getInputProps}) => {
      return (
        <div
          {...getRootProps()}
        >
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          {
          <p>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</p>
          }
        </div>
      )
  }}
</Dropzone>
      </div>

      <div>

        {this.state.uploadedFileCloudinaryUrl === '' ? null :
        <div>
          <p>{this.state.uploadedFile.name}</p>
          <img src={this.state.uploadedFileCloudinaryUrl} />
        </div>}

      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: What does your response object look like?

Answer (score 0):

To deal with null or undefined, you could change conditional to:
`if ( response.body.secure_url && response.body.secure_url !== '' )`

This checks to make sure the secure URL exists with some truthy value before determining whether or not it is not equal to the empty string (because technically null is not equal to the empty string so the existing condition does not check everything you are interested in).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code in React on how to use it with upload:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/jq4wl1xjv